# MicroProfile HealthCheckResponse JUnit

Tags: junit, health-check, microprofile

We are writing a JUnit for a method which uses Microprofile Health checks. The following code is throwing errors due to incorrect use of mock.

```
try (MockedStatic<HealthCheckResponse> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(HealthCheckResponse.class))
    {
        utilities.when(() -> HealthCheckResponse.named(anyString()))
            .thenReturn(HealthCheckResponse.builder().name("connectivity-check").up().build());

        final ConnectivityCheck connectivityCheck = new ConnectivityCheck();
        final HealthCheckResponse healthCheckResponse = connectivityCheck.call();

        assertEquals("connectivity-check", healthCheckResponse.getName());
        assertEquals(HealthCheckResponse.Status.UP, healthCheckResponse.getStatus());
    }
```

The following exception is thrown.

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.utils.health.ConnectivityCheckTest.testConnectivityCheckSuccess(ConnectivityCheckTest.java:75)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is completed
```

It is something to do with the following line. Issue is with mocking HealthCheckResponse class since it has static methods.

```
utilities.when(() -> HealthCheckResponse.named(anyString()))
            .thenReturn(HealthCheckResponse.builder().name("connectivity-check").up().build());
```

Please let me know if there is any example of writing a test case for Microprofile Health checks with mocking.